# Bevel end blending

Tags: geometry, bevel

Still very nooby at this, so bear with me.

Are there easy ways to tidy up the end of bevels like this? I'd like to bevel the edge but not the center part.
[image]

Looking more for this shape, but with the yawning void filled. Can it be done faster that what I do now, which is to seperate the objects, bevel them seperately, rejoin them and then fill the gaps manually.

[image]

Cheers everyone.

Comment: I've given an alternative method, but depending on what geometry you actually need it can be done very easily... let's say you don't need that vertical connecting edge and (obviously from your screenshots) n-gons are okay, then simply do only the very first step from the answer @moonboots has given: join the top and bottom vertices with `J`, then you are already finished.

Comment: Oh, I meant horizontal connecting edge, not vertical ‍♂️

Answer (score 5):

You could create this edge with <kbd>J</kbd>:

[image]

Then this one with the *Knife* tool:

[image]

Dissolve these edges:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, both methods work perfectly! :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Make sure you are in *Vertex Select* mode and *Snapping* is set to *Vertex* as well. Then select the vertex going to the back (right in the image) of that non-planar face.

   [image: select vertex]
2. Press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to enable the *Vertex Slide* tool and move the vertex to the back (right in the image) along the horizontal edge.

   [image: vertex slide]
3. Now press <kbd>C</kbd> to disable the *Clamp* on this edge. You will see the yellow slide line extend to the front. Move the vertex now towards the beveled part.

   [image: disable clamp]
4. While you slide it forward, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and move your mouse towards one of the front vertices of the face to snap to it. It is now flush with the top and bottom vertices. Then you can left-click to confirm the action.

   [image: snap vertex slide]

This would be enough, if you want the exact mesh like shown in your bottom image, feel free to add these steps:

5. Select the two vertices for the vertical edge above the bevel and press <kbd>J</kbd> to connect them.

   [image: join vertices]
6. In *Edge Select* mode select the two edges that are missing in your screenshot and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Edges*.

   [image: dissolve edges]

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, both methods work perfectly! :)